# windows cookies index.dat parser

Tags: python, perl, internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-8

Could someone explain how Internet Exploer cookies stored and how it retrived using the index.dat ,also could someone provide how this binray file is built and if there are a paserer/module/library for it written on perl /python ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_History_File_Format

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [HTTP::Cookies::Microsoft](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aCookies%3a%3aMicrosoft), part of [libwww-perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a series of blog posts I wrote about index.dat:

- [Index.dat: Part I - What is index.dat?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffdav/archive/2004/11/18/266027.aspx)
- [Index.dat: Part II - What are they used for?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffdav/archive/2004/11/18/266045.aspx)

Basically you'll need to be able to call the wininet [UrlCacheEntry APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385473%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from Perl.  I think there is a win32 module that let's you do this.